# Can't connect to Windows 7 Homegroup with Windows 8

Tags: windows-8-preview

I have a computer running Windows 7 with all my data on it, and with a Homegroup. My gf's laptop running Windows 7 HP is still connected to the group, but the Windows 8 Dev Preview is not seeing the Homegroup. The troubleshooter isn't running, and I can ping the main computer by WINS name. My VM of Windows 7 still connects as well. Any ideas what may be blocking it? I haven't installed MSE or any other security programs yet

**Edit**: It saw the homegroup after rebooting and choosing trusted network, but it won't accept my homegroup password

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It worked for me.

I copied the password from the Windows 7 machine.

Used Remote Desktop to my Windows 8 laptop.

Pasted.

Eureka!  It joined.

I shared my music and documents.

I checked explorer on both machines.  Accounts showed up just as they do with pure Windows 7 homegroup members.

Good luck, I hope it helps to know its possible.

Comment: Thanks Guy Thomas. I've been trying to join a newly formatted laptop on Windows 8 for days. It would see the homegroup but when you type in the password it just won't accept it and would say the network is not available anymore. I guess using a remote desktop from a member of the homegroup to this unjoined laptop pokes a hole in its ports and allows the access.